# How to get input value and use in calculation with database price

Tags: php, html

Give a look at the line of code below:

```
$five = $row['fivemm']; //$five is the price per piece (database)

<input class="form-control-table" type="text" name="fivemm" id="fivemm" value=""> </input>

<div class="row calculation"> <?php echo $five * input value; ?> </div>
```

Is there a possibility to to multiply a value from a database with an input value without javascript, so only with php?

Comment: Given that the php is provided from server side interaction and the input is provided from client-side interaction - there is no way of multiplying the two without javascript. You need the js to determine the value of the input, parse it to a number (if necessary) and then do rthe calculation nad update the result somewhere. Javascript is your friend.

Comment: ***gavgrif, He could do it if he sent the info to a new php via get/post form. He could set the "price per piece" as a hidden input and have the user select the amount to multiply by. But he probably wants the calculation to happen on the same page.

Comment: @gavgrif Unfortunately I have little experience with JS. Could you show me an example so I know where and how to start  I have already tried a few things to put the values ​​in variables but I don't know how to put them in a calculation in Js

Comment: @Vbudo - that is what I assumed - that the php and input would be calculated on the same page - with no form get / post involvment and since there is no js - equally no ajax implementation.

Comment: @Dedurex- you need to store the php value to a js variable (there are plenty of posts on that) and then on the keyup / blur / click etc of the input - pass the value of the input to a js function that takes the variable you created and multiples it and returns the result.